# React Sending Props to Children

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to send the data from index.js to App then distribute it to various components of the application. It's failing with `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` at this mark `render({ name, street, state })`

What's the problem here I don't understand?

I have the below test data that I am passing in:

```
let data = {
    from : {
      name: "Full Name",
      street: "123 Fake St.",
      state: "Boston, MA 02118",
    },
    to : {
      name: "Mrs. Receiver",
      street: "123 Fake St.",
      state: "San Francisco, CA 94101",
    }
  }
```

Then, I have this class to accept it and send it to its children

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const { from, to } = {...this.props.data }

    return (
      <div className="Envelope">
        <Stamp />
        <From data={ from } />
        <To data={ to } />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Then, I have this child for example:

```
  render({ name, street, state }) {
    return (
      <div className="From">
            <span>
                { name }
            </span>
            <br />
            <span>
                { street }
            </span>
            <br />
            <span>
                { state }
            </span>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working, and am posting the answer below.

So Firstly my files are like below:

```
-index.js
-app.js
--Components (folder)
--From.js
--To.js
```

Initially, I had the data declaration below

```
let data = {
  from : {
    name: "Full Name",
    street: "123 Fake St.",
    state: "Boston, MA 02118",
  },
  to : {
    name: "Mrs. Receiver",
    street: "123 Fake St.",
    state: "San Francisco, CA 94101",
  }
}
```

inside index.js and was sending the data to App.js by `<App data={data}` Instead, I moved it to App.js itself and removed the need of sending data to App.js. Then, I wrote below code for App.js:

```
<From
        name={data.from.name}
        street={data.from.street}
        state={data.from.state}
    />
    <To
        name={data.to.name}
        street={data.to.street}
        state={data.to.state}
    />
```

Which sends the data to From and To components. Then I wrote simple functions for From.js and To.js below:

From.js

```
export default function From({name, street, state}) {
  return (
    <div>
      {name} <br />
      {street} <br />
      {state}
    </div>
  )
}
```

To.js

```
import React from 'react'

export default function To({name, street, state}) {
  return (
    <div>
      {name} <br />
      {street} <br />
      {state}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Doing it like this helped me to understand the logic of props better, hope it will be helpful for people having issues in this regards...

Comment: actually you probably only need 1 Component which is called ´<Direction />´ and maybe a prop type to specify if its `to` or `from`

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if I got your question right.

render does not receive arguments.

You can wrap it in a presentational component.

```
const Child = ({name,street,state}) => (<div> className="From"> 
   <span>{ name }</span>
            <br />
    <span>{ street }</span>
            <br />
   <span>{ state }</span></div>)
```

and later use it like

```
<Child name={name} street={street} state={state} />
```

If you got more complex logic you should consider using a class and extending `React.Component`

Comment: So let's say we have 4 components, A imports B and B imports C and B also imports D. Data is in A, I want to send the data from A to B then B to its children C and D. If I create a const like this I wont be able to pass as a value only... @silverfighter

Comment: Basically you want just pass around props (remember if you use {somvar} you destructuring from props.somvar. There is also a special props-property called {children} that let's you do nesting <Child name={}.../><Address /></Child> (https://codeburst.io/a-quick-intro-to-reacts-props-children-cb3d2fce4891). Please adjust your question with your 4-Component-Scenario (and provide more detail) then I can adjust the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem seems to be that you're referring to `data` as `this.props.data` when it's a global variable.

So it should be `const { from, to } = {...data }`.